# why jasperreports 5.1.2 liberary dosen't work on intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, jasper-reports

when i tried to add jasper report jar file to my project in intellij it didn't work and i tried many virsios of the liberary but then when i tried it on netbeans it works.it gives me syntax error for example "Cannot resolve symbol 'JRBeanCollectionDataSource'" here is the classes i want to use:

```
`import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;`
```

Comment: What error/warning do you get?

Comment: it didn't work for the frist plase , it gives me syntax error for example "Cannot resolve symbol 'JRBeanCollectionDataSource'"

Comment: How did you add jasperreports library to the project?

Comment: i added it by the ordenary way to add jar on intellij and this lines of code from a tutorial

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with "Project Structure | Modules | Dependencies"? Also you may try to run "File | Invalidate Caches".